# How to display data in each menu from database in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel, I want to display the menu for each restaurant from the database, the list of Restaurants is in the home section and each restaurant must have a different menu

[image]

web.php:

```
Route::get("/Menu/", [HomeController::class, "menu"]);
```

HomeController:

```
public function menu()
    {

        $data=DB::table('restaurants_menu')
            ->select('*')
            ->get('*');

        return view('restaurant_menu',compact('data'));
    }
```

restaurant_menu.blade.php :

```
<div class="menu-container">
        @foreach($data as $data)

                <div class="box" >
                <div class="box-img">

                </div>

                <img src="{{$data->food_image}}"  alt="" height="200">
                <h2>{{$data->food_name}}</h2>
              <h2>{{$data->menu_id}}</h2>
              <h3>{{$data->food_description}}</h3>

            </div>
```

Comment: Do you have [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) set up already? _How_ do you want to display each menu, all on the "home" page? Does each restaurant get a dedicated page where you show more info about the restaurant along with its menu? What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I have two tables in the database, the first one is the restaurants ( contains the name, location, description, and the restaurant_id) the second table is the restaurants_menu (contains the food_name, food_image, food_description, food_price, restaurant_name and the menu_id which is equal to the restaurant_id from the first table ) my problem is when I display the menu  in the restaurants the whole menu will display, I want to display the specific menu for each restaurant, I will really appreciate your help

Comment: Set up [relations]([relations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)) between a restaurant and its menu, then I would have a route like `/Menu/{id}` point to a single restaurant/menu. In the method for the single restaurant you can get its menu via the `id` parameter from the route. `restaurant_name` is not really needed in your menu table since that is already in your restaurant table